Trouble with R Shiny app, leaflet map using tidygeocoder timing out
I am making a shiny app where you can enter any address and it should find the nearest airport to that address and also the nearest office (of four) to suggest a best path. I have a sf file for the offices and airports, so I am only using tidygeocoder for geocoding the input address into lat long. When I run the code as lines outside of the app, it works and I get the resulting map I imagine. In the shiny app, it stalls out after a few seconds and I get this message:
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4256
Passing 1 address to the Nominatim single address geocoder
[=====================================================================] 1/1 (100%) Elapsed:  1s Remaining:  0s
but no real error message.
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
library(sf)
library(tidygeocoder)
library(here)  



# Load office locations and airports data

office_locations <- st_read("office_xy.shp")
airports <- st_read("airports_xy.shp")


# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Find Closest Office and Airport"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("address", "Enter your address:"),
      actionButton("submit", "Submit")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput("map")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(data = office_locations, label = ~Name)
  })
  
  
  
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    # Geocode user's address
    geocoded_address <- tidygeocoder::geo(input$address)
    geocoded_coords <- c(geocoded_address$long, geocoded_address$lat)
    geocoded_sf <- st_as_sf(geocoded_address, coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326)
    closest_office <- which.min(st_distance(geocoded_sf, office_locations))
    closest_airport <- which.min(st_distance(geocoded_sf, airports))
    
    # Find latitude and longitude coordinates of closest office and airport using ID
    closest_office_coords <- office_locations[office_locations$ID == closest_office, c("lat", "long")]
    closest_airport_coords <- airports[airports$ID == closest_airport, c("lat", "long")]
    
    # Create map connecting closest office to closest airport
      map <- leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(data = office_locations, label = ~Name)  %>%
      addPolylines(
        lng = c(closest_office_coords$long, closest_airport_coords$long),
        lat = c(closest_office_coords$lat, closest_airport_coords$lat),
        color = "blue"
      ) %>%
      addPolylines(
        lng = c(geocoded_coords[1], closest_airport_coords$long),
        lat = c(geocoded_coords[2], closest_airport_coords$lat),
        color = "red"
      )
    
    # Return the map
    map
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

I have tried using different geocoding services, but tidygeocoder seems to work the best in the plain code.

Your example isn't reproducible, which makes it hard for people to help - we don't have your .shp files. A couple of general suggestions though - turn everything above # Create map in your observeEvent into a function and make sure that is returning what you expect it to. You'll also want to create a leafletProxy and use that inside the observeEvent so that you don't have to re-render the whole map every time the inputs change.
